# How to get link path in custom block for a view?

Tags: 7, views, theming

I created a view (unformatted) associated with a content type with two simple fields for a block.
The view is called "phrases" have generated two .tpl:

a) **views-view-unformatted--phrases-block.tpl.php** (to style row).

b) **views-view-fields--phrases-block.tpl.php** (to style the fields).

How to generate the link to the content, because by the variables I do not receive the direction I need.

I have available only the variable "$content", but this is formatted with something like:

```
<span class = "field-xx-xx"> 
     <a href="path/to/correct/content">Path</a>
</span>
```

I need to assign a class to the **"a tag"** , but as I receive all formatting can not.

Example i need:

```
<div class="my-class"> 
    <a class="my-link-class" href="path/to/correct/content">Path</a>
</div>
```

As I can generate the correct path to the content?

Comment: You can get the node id and then: $url = url('/node/'. $nid);

Comment: ugly way to do it, you don't want to use nid's in urls. You want to use aliases. ie: `/articles/how-to-use-drupal` instead of `node/1`

Comment: @NoSssweat : why?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens it's not good for SEO and also it just looks amateurish.

Comment: @NoSssweat : OK, that helps to understand your comment, merci!

Comment: The url function returns the url alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view, in FIELDS add `Content: Path`

Then in **views-view-fields--phrases-block.tpl.php** add:

```
<div class="my-class"> 
    <a class="my-link-class" href="<?php print $fields["field_path"]->raw; ?>">Path</a>
</div>
```

if the above doesn't work try:

```
<a class="my-link-class" href="<?php print $fields["field_path"]->content; ?>">Path</a>
```

If the 1st and 2nd doesn't work, to make the 2nd one work, get rid off all your html markup, because it's probably printing as `href="<span>/yourpath</span>"`

Click on your Path field and unchecked add default classes.

[image]

In field settings, uncheck add field wrappers.

[image]

Comment: Thanks , had made a mistake, I was using the wrong (field link) field, but with the "path field" have solved the problem.